# How can I do a cast that involves var?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I’m trying to do a cast that involves var. I have initialized my variable like this:

```
var updateContent = (MyType)null;

if (correctTime)
{
    var getDataFromDatabase = from d in db.Content where d.someId == id select d;

    //Here's where my I need to do some type of cast.
    updateContent = getDataFromDatabase
}
```

Is there a correct cast that I can use to store getDataFromDatabase in updateContent?

UPDATE:

Sorry my questions was unclear.  Based on all your comments I was able to accomplish the following:

```
    IEnumerable<MtType> updateContent = null;

                  if (correctTime==true)
                    {

                       IEnumerable<MtType> getDataFromDatabase = var getDataFromDatabase = from d in db.Content where d.someId == id select d;                           
                       updateContent = getDataFromDatabase;
                     }
```

My final objective was to be able to access returns from inside an if block and this did the trick.  Thanks again for all your help.

Comment: It's not clear what exactly you're trying to cast to. Do you want to cast just one item or are you trying to cast the whole collection?

Comment: Your problem is still the same without `var`. `var updateContent = (MyType) null;` is `MyType updateContent = null;` And then your problem is *I'm trying to assign IQueryable<T> to MyType but it's not working...* If we generously assume that `d` is already `MyType` then just `IQueryable<MyType> updateContent = null;`

Comment: I'm trying to cast every item in the collection.

Comment: [`IEnumerable.Cast<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/bb341406(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @CloudyKooper Then look at Linq's `.Cast<T>()`

Answer (score 3):

The result from you query will be an `IEnumerable<Content>`. If you want to load the results from your query into `MyType` then you need to do a projection like this:

```
var getDataFromDatabase = from d in db.Content where d.someId == id
  select new MyType { Prop1 = d.Prop1, Prop2 = d.Prop2 };
```

This will give you an `IQueryable<MyType>`, which in turn inherits `IEnumerable<MyType>`, in `getDataFromDatabase`

If you just want to get the the first `MyType` from you query results, then you can do:

```
updateContent = getDataFromDatabase.FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: *This will give you an `IEnumerable<MyType>` in getDataFromDatabase* Highly likely it's an `IQueryable<MyType>` as well.

Comment: I want to get the entire collection.  After using select new MyType { Prop1 = d.Prop1, Prop2 = d.Prop2 }; I'm getting "An explicit cast exists, (are you missing a cast?).

Comment: Just do `getDataFromDatabase.ToList()` to get a `List<MyType>`

Answer (score 1):

The keyword `var` is just a handy abbreviation for the concrete type. It is **not** something like a dynamic type or so. As quite a lot of commentors stated before, the two following lines are identical

```
var myVar1 = (MyType)null;

MyType myVar2 = (MyType)null;
```

The only difference is that the typecast can be ommited in the second line. So, and this was mentioned as well, you are trying to assign an `IEnumerable<OfSomeType>` to a variable of `MyType` which simply does not and will never work.

Resharper's refactoring options allow you to switch between implicit (`var`) and explicit (`MyType`) declaration.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that in the code following what you posted there's a check to see if `updateContent` is `null`.

This seems like a really good application of the [conditional operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx):

```
var updateContent = correctTime 
    ? (from d in db.Content where d.someId == id select d)
    : null;
```

Comment: Thanks everyone, your comments steered me in the right direction.  I've added the solution to my original comment.  Thanks again for all your help!